# How to use max(Date) and Distinct in Oracle DB. I would like to get data inserted very last within a day

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, where-clause, greatest-n-per-group

I am looking for a way to fetch Data.
by
latest date In the same day
by UserId

```
UserId,Value1,Date
1, 2030,2020–09-07 10:58:58
1, 2020,2020–09-07 05:58:28
1, 2050,2020–09-08 19:58:28
2, 3000,2020–09-07 10:58:18
2, 2001,2020–09-06 10:58:55
3, 2400,2020–09-08 10:28:53
4, 2400,2020–09-07 13:28:53
```

e.g

```
where Date >=  trunc(TO_DATE(’20200907’,’YYYYMMDD’))   and Date < trunc(TO_DATE(’20200908’,’YYYYMMDD’))
```

Ideal Result

```
UserId,Value
1,2050 
2,3000
4,2400
```

select UserId, value
What should I use ?

```
 max(Date) ? Distinct userId ?  Group  by userId?
```

Answer (score 0):

If `value` is the only column you want, then you could use `keep`:

```
select userid, max(value1) keep(dense_rank last order by dt) value1
from mytable
where dt >= date '2020-09-07' and dt < date '2020-09-08'
group by userid
order by userid
```

Notes:

- this uses the standard `date` syntax rather than `to_date()` to build literal dates
- `date`is a reserved word in Oracle, hence not a good choice for a column name; I renamed it to `dt` in the query.

If you want more columns in the resultset, then filtering with window functions is more appropriate:

```
select t.*
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by userid order by dt desc) rn
    from mytable t
    where dt >= date '2020-09-07' and dt < date '2020-09-08'
) t
where rn = 1
```